# qt connectNotify usage

Tags: qt

I have a QT class instance, called C,  (C inherits QOBJECT) that sends a signal S.
In my program, other QT classes instances X are created and destroyed when the program runs. These other classes connect and disconnect S, i.e. they run:

```
connect(C,SIGNAL(S()), this, SLOT(my_func()));  // <this> is an instance of X
```

or

```
disconnect(C,SIGNAL(S()), this, SLOT(my_func()));
```

In class C, the calculation of whether S should be emitted (and the data associated to it - not shown here) is rather complicated, so I would like the instance of class C (which emits the signal) to be notified when one(or more) object are connected (listening) to S or when all are disconnected.

I have read about the **connectNotify** and **disconnectNotify** functions, but their usage is discouraged. Besides the documentation does not state very clearly if there is a one to one relationship between the number of (dis)connectNotify calls and the number of "listener" to the signal (or can one single connectNotify be called for more than one listener?).

Can I just count positively (count++) the number of connectNotify and negatively (count--) the number of disconnectNotify and just react to non-zero value?

Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you've got it right that `connectNotify` and `disconnectNotify` can be used for this purpose - each `connect` event will be counted properly, even if it is a duplicate from the same object.

You can also double check this with [QObject::receivers](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#receivers)

> int QObject::receivers ( const char * signal ) const [protected]
>   Returns the number of receivers connected to the signal. Since both
>   slots and signals can be used as receivers for signals, and the same
>   connections can be made many times, the number of receivers is the
>   same as the number of connections made from this signal. When calling
>   this function, you can use the SIGNAL() macro to pass a specific
>   signal:  if (receivers(SIGNAL(valueChanged(QByteArray))) > 0) {
>        QByteArray data;
>        get_the_value(&data);       // expensive operation
>        emit valueChanged(data);  } As the code snippet above illustrates, you can use this function to avoid emitting a signal that
>   nobody listens to. Warning: This function violates the object-oriented
>   principle of modularity. However, it might be useful when you need to
>   perform expensive initialization only if something is connected to a
>   signal.

My suggestion would be to write a simple test program.  Override `connectNotify` and `disconnectNotify` to increment/decrement a counter, but also use `receivers` to verify that the counter is correct.  Try connecting multiple times, disconnecting multiple times, disconnecting even if there is no connection, etc.

Something to be careful of: `connect` and `disconnect` are thread-safe; I'm not sure if the matching `Notify` functions are safe also.

Answer (score 0):

Since Qt 5.0, you can do this more easily with the [`QObject::isSignalConnected` function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#isSignalConnected). Example from the documentation:

```
static const QMetaMethod valueChangedSignal = QMetaMethod::fromSignal(&MyObject::valueChanged);
if (isSignalConnected(valueChangedSignal)) {
    QByteArray data;
    data = get_the_value();       // expensive operation
    emit valueChanged(data);
}
```

Comment: Qt 5.15.0 QObject::isSignalConnected always returns false?

Comment: @EdoftheMountain That sounds like you might want to open a new question for it (with code that demonstrates the problem).